# How to share prepared files on build stage between containers with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 services: `nginx` and `web`

When I build `web` image I build the frontend via the command `npm install && npm run build`

But I need prepared files in both containers: in the `web` and in the `nginx`.

How to share files between containers (images)? I can't simply use volumes, because they will be mounted only in runtime.

Comment: you must use volumes

Answer (score 0):

The [Dockerfile `COPY` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) can copy files from an arbitrary image.  While it's most commonly used in multi-stage builds, you can use it with *any* image, even one you built yourself.

Say your `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: my/web
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports: [8000:80]
```

Note that we've explicitly given the `web` image a name; also notice that there are no `volumes:` in this setup.

In the proxy image, we can then copy files out of that image:

```sh
# Dockerfile.nginx
FROM nginx
COPY --from=my/web /app/static /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The only complication here is that Compose doesn't know that one image is built off of the other.  You'll probably have to manually tell it to rebuild the application image so that it gets built before the proxy image.

```sh
docker-compose build web
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

You can use this in a more production-oriented setup to deploy this application without having the code directly available.  You can create a base `docker-compose.yml` that names an `image:` for both containers, and then [add a separate `docker-compose.override.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) that has the `build:` blocks.  After running `docker-compose build` twice as above, you can `docker-compose push` the built images, and then run this container stack on your production system getting the images from the registry; without a local copy of the source tree and without volumes.